# "Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API" error on Windows 7 using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, winsock2

When starting Tomcat 6 on Windows 7 Enterprise with JRE 6 using
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin\tomcat6.exe
the application does not open and my event viewer has the message:

"Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API."

The same installer of Tomcat worked on Windows Vista before I upgraded my operating system.

Can anyone please suggest a way to fix this?

The only site I can find mentioning this is 
http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=4418
which suggests using this config setting "Win32DisableAcceptEx" - but it's for Apache, not Tomcat, and I have no idea where in what config file it might need to go in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the Tomcat user mailing list by Caldarale, Charles R:

Download the latest Java JDK.
Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the top level JDK folder.
Download the zip version of Tomcat, not the exe installer.
Start it using the startup.bat script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment (*add **#** befor*) `Win32DisableAcceptEx` directive in **httpd.conf** then restart apache.
more details in [Apache MPM winnt Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_winnt.html)